# Hosting Restful WCF Service without SVC and Config file - possible?

Tags: wcf, rest, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to host the WCF Service without SVC or Config file with MVC?

Comment: Why not use WebAPI? It's works well together with MVC projects.